# Matlab Individual Patch Coloring

Tags: matlab

Is there any way to modify the colors of specific faces in a patch object? I'm using `patch(fv)` to generate a patch. In my case, I have a golf ball, and I want to change one of the dimple's colors to black.

```
fv = stlread('golfball.stl');
patch(fv,'FaceColor',[0.8,0.8,1.0],...
         'EdgeColor','none',...
         'FaceLighting','gouraud',...
         'AmbientStrength',.15);
material('shiny');
```

This generates the golfball for me. How can I parse the `fv` structure to change one of dimple's colors?

Thanks!

Comment: The fourth argument to `patch` specifies color of each vertex or face. See the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html)

Comment: In that case, how do I query the `fv` structure to grab the face that I want? I'm currently grabbing the `fv` by using [stlread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6678-stlread)

Comment: I don't know, sorry. Maybe someone can answer that. Or post your code (a minimal example) and that way it will be easier for you to get help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the demo provided by the author of `stlread.m` (`stldemo.m`), it looks like `fv` has 2 fields, `faces` and `vertices`. You can get this by running

```
fv = stlread('femur.stl');
Names = fieldnames(fv)
```

I hope I'm not completely off the track, but my understanding is that  you could access each face/vertex individually and change its color as you would do for any patch object.

Hope that helps somehow!

Comment: This got me on the right track. To further dive into the details, as long as I pull the number of faces I want and then the corresponding vertices (3 times as many), I can trial and error my way into completing the patch.

     `fv2.faces = fv.faces(1:30,1:3);
     fv2.vertices = fv.vertices(1:90.1:3);`

and then calling `patch` works.

Thanks!

Comment: ok great! You can accept the answer if this helped you solve your problem. Thanks and good luck!